# Where can I find Amazon Free Tier end date?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to find my Free Tier end date on my Amazon console but cannot find it. Any help about where I can find this information?

PS.: If this is not the right place for this type os question, could you please point tell me the right place for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS will send you Expiration notice before 10-15 days. There is no active tracking  available. Either you have to count that from the day your account was created or wait for that Expiration Notice email.